# RightBarButtonItem Does Not Appear in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

This is bugging the heck out of me! I'm just trying to programmatically add a right-side "flash" button to my navigation bar, and for whatever reason, I can't make it appear.  My code is below.  Can anyone help me?  Thanks in advance.

```
 //Note: flashButton is declared as a UIButton property in .h, and synthesized in .m        
    UIView *flashContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 36)];

    [flashButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleTorch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [flashButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"FlashIconInactive_small.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [flashButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"FlashIconActive_small.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [flashContainer addSubview:flashButton];
    [flashButton sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem *flashButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:flashContainer];

    scannerVC.delegate = self;
    scannerVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelTapped)];
    [[scannerVC navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:flashButtonItem];
```

Comment: so the left button works just fine? it's just the right one?

Comment: Correct, @Nabou, the left button appears and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is flashButton connected to a button in a xib or storyboard via an IBOutlet? If not, you'll need to create an instance of UIButton using [+[UIButton buttonWithType:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIButton/buttonWithType%3a).

Another test to try is to set a breakpoint on your first line (the addTarget: one) and enter `po flashButton` in the debugger. What's the output? If it's nil, then your button doesn't exist and needs to be created.

Comment: I have declared 'UIButton *flashButton' and made it a property in my .h (synthesized in my .m) file.  I am doing this all programmatically and not utilizing a XIB/Storyboard.  @Kris is this not enough?

Comment: @JRoss, No. You have to allocate memory for the button. You can use `+[UIButton buttonWithType:]` for this. And if you have declared as `@property`, you need to use it as `self.flashButton` and not `flashButton` alone.

Comment: Thanks @Kris!  I feel like an idiot, but sometimes I forget the basics!  I added the following line to make my code work: 

flashButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Comment: @JRoss, You still need to change it to `self.flashButton` if you want to make use of @property, which Kris forgot to mention.

Comment: I removed the property/synthesize and it works fine.  I figured my viewController did not need to have it as a property.  Is there a reason I should make it a property? @ACB

Comment: Only if you are using it in multiple methods across the class, you need to use it as property. Otherwise you dont need it.

Comment: Hmmmm...  Well I am using the instance in another method that get's called after pushing the "flash" button, and it seems to work fine without previously declaring it as a property.  In this additional method, I am setting the image of the button to it's active state.  Should I be declaring the UIButton instance as a property and why @ACB?

Comment: If that method is this button's action method, you may not have to worry much. But otherwise @property can handle memory management for you. It will retain the object and makes sure that app wont get crashed.